# ActionBar is not visible with Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

In my App, there is an activity which has a layout as the one posted below. the problem I have is, when that activity starts, action bar becomes invisible, CoordinatorLayout takes up all the screen.
What I am trying to do is that actionBAr should be visible. The action bar of the my App looks like the image shown in section "action bar" below.

To solve this problem I did the following:

i added "FloatingButtonTheme" to the styles.xml file as shown below in "styles.xml". and in the manifest file I added the following code:

```
<activity 
    android:name="x.xx.xxx.activity.ListeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/FloatingButtonTheme">
```

but the result I got is that the activity takes up all the space on the screen with floating button appearing but the action bar is never there.

Please let me know how to force my action bar just as in picture below to show up?

Actually, this problem only appears when I use the

**activity layout**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.VersiecherungsListeActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/versicherungslisteactivity_vers_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/versicherungslisteactivity_fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_orange" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**action bar**:

[image]

**sytles**:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
<style name="FloatingButtonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

Comment: post this layout code `versicherungslisteactivity_vers_view` ??

Comment: @Ironman ok i added it

Comment: Would you remove  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: @user2121 add `Toolbar` as `Ravish Sharma` answer if you are not added in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just added android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" to the CoordinatorLayout as shown below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.VersiecherungsListeActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <include layout="@layout/versicherungslisteactivity_vers_view" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/versicherungslisteactivity_fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_orange" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Tool Bar below coordinator layout :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

And in activity

```
ToolBar toolbar =(ToolBar)finfViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: should i add it inside "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout"? or i should remove the "android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout"??

Comment: yes you can add it inside app bar layout ,you can also add it below coordinator layout  it totally depends on your layout behaviour

Comment: Are you Working on Tab layout or something else tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `appbar` and `toolbar` to your xml, or just `toolbar`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: but the app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" is not defined

Comment: Did you try to delete it? Or add: `<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />` to your `style` xml

Comment: concerning "android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"..there no resources found that matches the given name

Comment: Did you open your `styles.xml` file and added that line: `<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />` ?

Comment: what about "@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"?? also there no resources found that matches the given name